# Is it possible to have a completion block on the firestore query?

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a Firestore database reference that queries the data trying to find a user with a certain username. After I get the user I want to try to login. However, I have noticed that the block of code to query for a user, returns as soon as it is called. Is there any way to add a completion block or at least stop the program until it is done querying.

```
u.name = name
global.db.collection("users").whereField("username", isEqualTo: u.name).getDocuments(completion: { (snap, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        return
    }
    for doc in (snap?.documents)! {
        u.email = doc.data()["email"] as! String
    }
})

Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: u.email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        return
    }
    print("Succesfully Logged In")
    self.toListSelector(user: u)
})
```

This is the link to the image of my Firestore database
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI1iY.png

Comment: There already *is* a completion block in your code: it's where you loop over the `snap?.documents`. As Josh answered, you'll want to move the `Auth.auth().signIn` code **into** the callback block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your `signIn` INSIDE the `getDocuments` handler, probably after the `for` loop?

Comment: Thanks I feel kind of stupid now that I see the answer.

Comment: I think everyone makes this kind of mistake at least once when starting out with asynchronous code.